# Writing a Unit Test Logger For Containerized Applications In C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, logging, xunit

I have a containerized xUnit application in C#, in which I want to run my tests.
One of my tests is like:

```
[Fact]
public void Add_adds_user_properly()
{
    //Testing...
}
```

Whenever I execute `dotnet test` command inside my container, i see something like this:

```
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: 1 s - 
Test.Unit.dll (net5.0)
```

But I'm looking for something like this when my test passes:

```
Add_adds_user_properly() <with green color>
```

Or when it fails:

```
Add_adds_user_properly() <with red color>
```

Any recommendation is appreciated.